# Issue with RC op-amp oscillator

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

I'm trying to understand how oscillators work and am currently working with an RC phase shift oscillator:

[image: RC_phase_shift_oscillator]

$$R_1, R_2, R_3 = 200 \Omega$$

$$C_1, C_2, C_3 = 4.7\text{nF}$$

one of the issues I'm having is that one source states that \$R_{\text{fb}} = 29R\$ for sustained oscillation yet when I set the resistor to \$5.8\text{k}\Omega\$ I get a flat line in nV.

What am I missing out?

Comment: Are you simulating the circuit or testing it experimentally?

Comment: I'm running it in multisim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems.

1 - The biggest is that you have no excitation. That is, your simulator will provide a perfectly balanced set of operating points, and the circuit will have no reason to start oscillating. Try adding a circuit to provide a brief pulse into the - input just after startup. Adding a noise generator to the input to simulate real op amp noise performance will do the trick, too.

2 - Assuming you are doing transient analysis, a perfect gain (your 29) will cause an oscillation which never grows larger. Try a feedback value of 40 times, rather than 29, and you'll see the oscillation grow fairly rapidly. Start with a simulation time of at least 50 msec, then tailor as necessary. Once you see this, start reducing the gain ratio, and you'll see the startup time gradually increase.

3 - As is true of any open-loop oscillator, if you have enough gain to sustain oscillation, you almost certainly have too much gain, and the amplitude of oscillation will grow exponentially until the amp starts clipping. Real oscillators require some sort of automatic gain control in order to provide a low-distortion waveform.

Comment: Thanks adjusted the Rf to 8k and got small but stable oscillations increased to 20k and got clipped oscillations. Makes much more sense now thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To answer the other half of your question, RC Phase-Shift Oscillators work through essentially a delay means. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)#Phase_shift) is a good explanation of phase shift. An [OpAmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) is used as the amplifier, because it has an "inverting input." All other parameters being equal, increasing the `+input` causes a + increase to the output, while *decreasing* the `-input` causes a + increase in the output. That's what is meant by "inverting input" and op-amps are very versatile because of this.

[C1-3 and R2-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_filter#Passive_filters) form a passive *(no gain)* high-pass *(allow higher frequencies through)* 2nd-order or "twin-T" *(two complete sets of resistor-capacitor pairs = stronger effect)* filter. A [highpass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter) filter blocks low frequencies, while allowing high frequencies through. (Calculations shown there.)

As a rapidly-changing signal emanates from the op-amp output, C3 cannot pass this fully to the leg tied to R3, so introduces some delay while C3 charges. C2 and R2 delay this again, adding to the total phase shift reaching the `-input`. The component values are generally chosen so that 180° of total shift (the desired oscillation frequency) is fed into `-input`. So if the output is being shifted to essentially an opposite value, and this is being fed to the inverting input, then the net result (two negatives) is positive feedback.

If the oscillator attempts to start up at too low of a frequency, the filter will not allow much of it through. (This is also why the circuit may start up without oscillating, and need a "kick" to get it rolling.) The delayed bit that does make it through, if strong enough, starts it oscillating at a frequency that *does* make it through the filter. Each successive oscillation attempts to produce an output frequency in which the filter network produces an exact 180° phase shift.

Note that there are literally thousands of op-amps, all with different specifications. To make one oscillate at 27MHz, a very fast type will be needed, as they introduce some phase shift at high frequencies themselves. (And/or, the filter network adjusted so that they, plus the op-amp phase shift, provides the desired output frequency.)

Also, since the output is directly feeding the filter network, any additional load you place on the output may affect the operating frequency. To get around this, use another op-amp as a [unity-gain buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Voltage_follower_.28unity_buffer_amplifier.29). Then anything can be connected to that, and it won't affect the oscillator.

Lastly, at 27MHz, parasitic effects will play a role in the actual output frequency. Such as if the design is tested on a solderless breadboard, the stray inductance and capacitance of the board itself will skew the results. If adjusted for during testing, then built on a printed circuit board, it probably will be skewed again, due to parasitic differences in circuit board traces vs. breadboard busses. These effects can be calculated and accounted for, or it can be constructed, measured, and values adjusted.

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: One note upon looking back - since multiple capacitors and resistors are used in the negative feedback path, each one of these will add a small temperature coefficient, which will cause the frequency to shift. The sum of these may make the oscillator rather temperature-sensitive. To combat this, the temp.co. of the op-amp and feedback components can be specified - i.e., to attempt to nullify the coefficients and thus, the temperature sensitivity.